# syntax to pass multiple variables into query

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try adding 2 columns, my query works fine

```py
('INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON_S, LOAD_DATE) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', [[content]] )
```

However, when I try to add another variable (string):

```py
('INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON_S, LOAD_ID, LOAD_DATE) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?), (?), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', [[content]], load_id)
```

I get an error that:

```
Bind variable ? not set.
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Why are you using brackets around the first column and no brackets around the second one?

Comment: the content is a json type. load_id is just a string. am i supposed to use square brackers? @Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments should be provided as tuple:

```
con.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (JSON_S, LOAD_ID, LOAD_DATE) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?), ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
    ,(content, load_id))
```

Comment: With this: ```([[content]], load_id)```, I would get ```Binding data in type (list) is not supported.```

Comment: @x89 Why not `(content, load_id)`? If content_id is not string then `(json.dump(content), load_id)`